# How to read more than 20 byte using pygatt

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using python's pygatt in order to subscribe to a device's charasteristic. The problem I have is that in the callback, I'm only receiving 20 bytes each time and I need the full 70-100byte answer.

Is there a workaround to be able to read more than 20 bytes using python and pygatt? Changing the default mtu size for example. (I don't know if this can be done)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that this is a known issue. [Here](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt/issues/142) is a link to the comment thread on github.